After magento version update from 2.4.3 to 2.4.7 the category information is not displayed in the admin
After magento version update from 2.4.3 to 2.4.7 the category information is not displayed in the admin.
If I try to save the category name or category url again, I get the text "category saved" with no error but the fields are still empty, but the information (category name) is displayed in the category tree.


You can check the logs. Also, try to reindex data and check the clearing cache. Have you integrated Redis cache? If yes, try clearing it.

Hi! No errors in the log files. I have also cleared the redis cache, but it does not work.

We upgraded from Magento 2.4.6.p4 to Magento 2.4.7 with only Developer Extension Issues with PHP 8.3.  You might try increasing php_value max_input_vars
I will check with our Development Team to see if they have more details.
Have a blessed week,
Richard Wendrock

Hi' Any news on this problem?
